# Heavy Metals in Leaves of Rice Plant in Organic and Conventional Rice Field

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, anova, t-test, multivariate-analysis

what statistical tool should I  use to compare heavy  metal concentration between organic and conventional rice field? the heavy  metals are Cadmium,Cobalt, Iron, Lead, and Chromium. What should I use if the variety of rice is ignored, and if the variety of rice will be considered

Answer (score 1):

Statistics is a tool that is useful only if one is able to translate the problem at hand, at least to some degree, into mathematical formalism. In your case this means you should probably start your analysis with the following questions:

1) What is my response variable of interest $Y$ and on what scale is it defined. I guess that heavy metal concentration is somehow positive continuous but it might by bounded from above $Y\in[0,1]$? Depending on your answer to this question you can think of a probabilitstic model that allows to describe the random behaviour of such a variable.

2) What are my covariates of interest and how are they coded and related to your response? In your case this might be related to the variety of rice. Depending on your research setting you should think clearly whether to include or exclude explaining covariates.

3) What kind statistical hypothesis you want to test? This typically starts with defining a Null Hypothesis as for example in your case: $"H_0":$ The concentration of heavy metal in an organic rice field is smaller, equal to the concentration of heavy metal in a conventional rice field. Or formalized if $Y_o$ ($Y_c$) is the concentration in an organic (conventional) rice field,  $H_0:Y_o\leq Y_c$. Then your research design, based on your probability model from above allows you to reject $H_0$ given some measure of certainty. In your case this could be for example a comparison of means if you ignore covariates or a regression-based test if you want to control for covariates. This however, also depends on the data at hand. I.e. whether you have cross-sectional information or time-series and/or panel data.